# Possibility of buying treyf meat in a kosher store

Tags: kashrut-kosher, transactions, hechsher-certification, slaughter-shochet-shecht, kashering-kosherization

Since meat may be sold to a consumer before kashering and traiboring, it is possible that parts of meat obtained from a kosher store may not be kosher.*  Ordinarily, one could guess whether the meat has been kashered/traibored according to the state in which it is sold. (That is, one assumes that a whole, fresh animal carcass is presumably not kashered/traibored, whereas a butchered cut probably is.)

However, since there is the flexibility to sell both kinds of meat in the store, does this mean we cannot assume, say, that a package labeled "beef fat" contains meat free of chailev?

*(Not theoretically, abstractly possible--but literally, by definition.)

Comment: For what purpose would the butcher have a "package labeled "beef fat""?

Comment: No idea, but I've seen it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know what the situation in other countries in, but for a very long time, the only meat sold in stores in America has been soaked and salted. Even if a kosher-labelled piece of meat has not been salted properly, it's בטל ברוב, as the overwhelming majority of meat is completely kosher.

...you used the word "treyf," by which you probably meant the colloquial sense of "not salted." If you meant to say that the animal was technically "treyf," or not kosher due to some physical problem (certain kinds of broken leg, tear in the lung etc.), we'd also assume that it's probably fine, because every animal that leaves a slaughterhouse in America has been checked (quickly, but checked), and if something is missed, then it's also בטל ברוב.

However, there are some really treyf pieces of meat that get through to the consumer. Most of the time you won't be able to tell, however, and can thus rely on the ביטול ברוב. All the same, there are certain problems that you can recognize in your store-bought chicken. The ones that you can find in poultry have been described by Rabbi Yisroel Belsky in an octapartite [video series](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/new-ou-kosher-dvd-explains-whats-wrong-with-this-chicken/) (named, aptly, "What's Wrong with this Chicken?" ;) that you can buy from the OU. (*I haven't checked, but I'm fairly certain that these videos can be found on Youtube as well. Search for "Belsky what's wrong with this chicken"*)

(*I threw out a chicken leg last night for having a problematic bruise, the kind of which was described in those videos. It's rare, but it happens...and most people don't realize it.*)

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks. By "treyf" I guess I meant containing the fat we're not supposed to eat; that is, chailev

Comment: Also, though--you can buy shechted meat straight from farms even in this country. In these cases some parts of the animal are for sure not kosher. Whether a random part of that animal would be kosher is I guess another question

Comment: I'm "speechless" when it comes to your answers on shechita topics. Ever consider giving a public lecture? Or would the chickens "cry"?

Comment: @SAH Yeah, I figured that's what you meant :) ....about buying meat straight from farms; usually the farmer will remove all the non-kosher parts for you, and salt it too. (*at least, the one farm I know that does this*)

Comment: @DanF I have spoken semi-publicly on the topic before; although [really public classes aren't always a good idea](http://www.jewishpress.com/news/breaking-news/animal-rights-extremists-force-cancellation-of-shechita-class/2014/05/04/).

Comment: @Shokhet - Holy cow ... I mean chickens! Thanks for the article link. I guess there's a good reason why the location of kosher farms is remote and not well publicized.

Comment: @Shokhet I only know one farm that does it, too. It's located somewhere that sounds like it could be mitzrayim...

Comment: @SAH Is it near [Goshen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goshen,_New_York)? :)

Comment: @Shokhet Yeah! You work there?

Comment: @SAH No, but I've been there a few times. We're talking about Franklin, right?

Comment: @Shokhet Franklin? Doesn't sound like what I'm talking about... the one I'm talking about is /in/ Goshen.

Comment: @Shokhet You know it?

Comment: @SAH I'm not sure. That's the only kosher/Jewish owned farm I know of in the area. Do they have dairy cows (chalav yisrael, organic, grass fed, not operated on) and chicken slaughter (organic) in the farm you're thinking of?

Comment: @SAH The farm I'm thinking of, apparently, [is in Swan Lake](http://www.vosizneias.com/136589/2013/07/21/swan-lake-ny-bethels-pelleh-poultry-continues-to-boom-with-kosher-consumers/)

Comment: @Shokhet Not sure about dairy cows but organic chicken slaughter--yes. Where I'm talking about, they speak Yiddish. Come visit!

Comment: @SAH I'd love to :) ... My Yiddish needs some work, though :-P

Comment: @Shokhet it has "Yiddish" in the name...

Comment: @SAH Is it "Pelleh Farms"?

Comment: @Shokhet Not Yiddish in the name, but "Yiddish" in the name!